# Cannot read custom php.ini settings in wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress with a custom contact page in my theme and I want to change the post_max_size setting to allow large file uploads. I have included a php.ini file in the wp-admin directory with these settings

```
post_max_size = 42M
upload_max_filesize = 40M
```

and the Wordpress phpinfo() plugin shows these being parsed correctly. Fine so far.

For easier code maintenance I don't want to work with hard-coded values in the script, but rather obtain them at runtime. The problem is, calling `ini_get('post_max_size')` on the page gives me the default setting `8M`, not the custom setting.

Is there any other way to get the "real" settings?

The ISP allows custom php.ini and overriding these settings. I also tried copying the php.ini to the active theme directory, but that didn't help.

Comment: Moving php.ini isn't going to do anything. It is just a configuration file that is loaded when you start your web server and lets php know how to behave. If you change it, restart Apache and the values should load. You could also just `ini_set('post_max_file',  '42M')`.

Comment: phpinfo() will tell you where all it looked to find .ini-type files. either you specified your memory limits on a file that's not being loaded, or is being overridden by another .ini/.htaccess file loaded later on. ini_get() returns the value that's in effect at the moment you make the call. so if you get 8m, then 8m is the current in-effect limit, and your settings were not seen/overriden.

Comment: minelli, I am not moving php.ini, I created a custom one. And this is read by wordpress as I mentioned. The ISP 1und1 allows such usage for shared hosting, and of course I cannot restart Apache.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I should have read more clearly.

Comment: Marc, the wp-admin/php.ini is shown as loaded in phpinfo(): `Loaded Configuration File /homepages/14/d522086542/htdocs/berlin/wp/wp-admin/php.ini`. There is no .htaccess directive for the `post_max_size` setting. Since this information comes from the plugin, perhaps there is something in Wordpress that's preventing the setting from being read?

Comment: I just tried minelli's tip `ini_set('post_max_size', '42M');` with `ini_get('post_max_size');` right after it. No go. Seems I can't set in the script!

Comment: Even a regular wp-admin/phpinfo.php shows `42M`! I'm stumped.